# AttributeError: 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, keras

I am new in coding. I am trying to get the score but unfortunately i am getting errors. I was using first import.keras until it gave me when i wanted to evaluate the score and predict.The training model happened well, i have gotten no problem there.It is after that, when i was aboout to get the score of my model that i got as error ImageDataGnerator: Object has no 'ndim'.
Then i looked for help and someone told me to use import.tensorflow.keras instead and i did it....

After training the model again,reaching that part in order to get the score and predict after i've gotten another error saying : ImageDataGenerator  object has no attribute shapes and a warning saying : 
**WARNING** **:** **tensorflow** **:** **Falling** **back** **from** **v2** **loop** **because** **of** **error** **:** **Failed** **to** **find** **data* **adapter** **that** **can** **handle** **input** **:**  **<** **class** **'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>** **,** **<** **class** **'NoneType'**

This is some of the code below.

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 
import cv2
import sys 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 


image_width, image_height = 150,150

Epochs =10
batch_size=45
Steps_per_epoch=190
Validation_data=20
num_classes = len(map_characters)




model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape= (image_height,image_width ,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
opt = Adam(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, )

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',   
              metrics=['accuracy'])'''

train_datagen= ImageDataGenerator (
 rescale=1./255,
 shear_range=0.2,
 zoom_range=0.2,
 horizontal_flip=True)



test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) 

training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
 train_data_dir, 
 target_size = (image_height, image_width),
 batch_size = batch_size, 
 class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
 validation_data_dir, 
 target_size = (image_height, image_width), 
 batch_size = batch_size, 
 class_mode = 'categorical') 



result=model.fit_generator(training_generator, 
                   steps_per_epoch=Steps_per_epoch,
                   epochs = Epochs, 
                   validation_data = validation_generator,
                   validation_steps=Validation_data) 

score = model.evaluate(test_datagen,
                  validation_generator,
                  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate on a generator, you need to use `evaluate_generator`, not `evaluate`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.Actually , i am not trying to evaluate on a generator, i am trying to get the score and predict. I have evaluated the generator already and it is working . It is just the predicting part that is not working

Comment: @Franck-paulinPehnMayo There is no call to predict in your code, so not sure what you mean, your question has to actually represent what you are asking.

Comment: sorry , it was just an overview  of the whole project..... The problem is this '''score = model.evaluate(test_datagen,
                  validation_generator,
                  batch_size=batch_size)'''    when i reach this level after the training i am getting an error  'ImageDataGenerator' has  'shape'

Comment: i meant ImageDataGenerator has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my answer solves, please try reading it again. Use evaluate_generator, not evaluate.

Comment: yes , i tried that. I am getting an error saying: TypeError: evaluate_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'

Comment: Remove the batch size argument

Comment: i tried to remove it ....but it is the same problem.ImageDatagenerator has no attribute shape

Comment: do you think the problem can come from this: WARNING : tensorflow : Falling back from v2 loop because of error : Failed to find data* **adapter that can handle input : < class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'> , < class 'NoneType'

Comment: You should include the updated code and the full traceback in the question itself, single line error messages are not that useful.